# In a Django unit test driver how do you test if an email is sent?

Tags: django, django-testing

In a Django unit test driver how do you test if an email is sent?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a Django guru (to put it mildly) but it looks like there is some documentation on testing email here: [Testing Django Applications | E-mail services](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#e-mail-services).  Note that the demonstrated approach is for Django 1.0 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code for a forgot password api call

```
def test_forgot_password(self):
    """
        This test makes sure the forgot password api call is working ...
    """

    data = {
        'username' : self.user.email,
    }

    self.assertTrue(self.user.forgot_pw_hash is None)
    response = self.c.post(reverse('api_forgot_password'), data, HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')

    # make sure there is an email in the out box and make sure
    # the subject is correct
    self.assertEquals(mail.outbox[0].subject,'Reset Password')
    self.assertTrue(User.objects.get(email=self.user.email).forgot_pw_hash is not None)
```